# как записать в массив числа textbox?

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, textbox

как записать в массив числа из textbox разделенных пробелом? Допустим, пользователь ввел 12 12 4 6 7 9 - получилось 6 элементов массива, b[0] = 12, b[1] = 12, ..., b[5]=9.

```
private TextBox[] textBox1;
private TextBox[] textBox2;

...
public EnterColsAndRows(int width, int height)
}

    textBox1 = new TextBox[width_of_nonogram];
    textBox2 = new TextBox[height_of_nonogram];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stringFromTextBox = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
var numbers = stringFromTextBox.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Если между числами может быть несколько пробелов подряд, то

```
var stringFromTextBox = "1 2 3 4  5 6";
var numbers = stringFromTextBox.Split(new[] {" "}, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: а есть альтернативный вариант для динамически созданных textbox?

Comment: @y47999 если вы из динамически созданного текстбокса можете текст получить, то код дальше будет точно такой же, как в ответе

Comment: а можна пожалуйста пример, а то я плохо в этом розбираюсь в этом?

Comment: @y47999 пример чего? Вы ж никакого значимого кода не указали в вопросе, не показали как вы с текстбоксами работаете, как вы из них текст вытаскиваете, то есть по сути мне и пример то не от чего отталкивать, потому я только ответил на поствленный вопрос